# JPA - My Named Query won't work

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am having some problems, with the first time I've gotten into JPA. This is the query I'd like to put in as an @NamedQuery, and this SQL works.

```
select t1.*, t2.SHORT_NAME from ePluribusWS.GRAPH_ACL t1 join DB_AUTH.USERS t2 on t1.USER_ID = t2.ID where GRAPH_ID = 31611 ;
```

I'm not sure if this is supported within JPA, since I'm doing a JOIN across different databases, but within the same server. The SQL works fine.

When I try and add this in as a named query (the third one below) I get an error message (Syntax error parsing) that "A path expression cannot end with a comma" which the only Google'ing of shows me JPA source code which generated the error message.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GRAPH_ACL", catalog = "ePluribusWS", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
.
.
    @NamedQuery(name = "EPluribusACLEntryRecord.findByUserId", query = "SELECT g FROM ACLEntryRecord g WHERE g.userId = :userId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EPluribusACLEntryRecord.findByGraphId", query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.SHORT_NAME FROM ACLEntryRecord t1 JOIN DB_AUTH.USERS t2 ON t1.USER_ID = t2.ID WHERE t1.GRAPH_ID = :graphId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EPluribusACLEntryRecord.findByCreated", query = "SELECT g FROM ACLEntryRecord g WHERE g.created = :created"),
```

I'm sort of confused, since it looked like the JPA annotations required that they end with a comma.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question, and provide any insight. Normally, editors remove this "thanks" section, which I think is sort of an unpleasant edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A NamedQuery is JPQL, not SQL. There is no "*" and "DB_AUTH.USERS" is an invalid construct in JPQL ... has to refer to entities relative to the candidate entity (the entity defines where its schema is).

If you wanted to refer to tables that are not mapped to entities then you would have to use an SQL query (NamedNativeQuery)